# error with PhotoView : Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, dart

I have read few stackoverflow posts about "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe" error but couldn't find an answer which work.

I've tried to set a global key with the scaffold, and to use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() without success.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something stupid and easy to fix, but I can't figure out what.

This is a simple version of the code which replicates the error when you go back from PhotoViewPage ([photo_view package](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view)) :

> my_home_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phototest/photo_view_page.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: const Text("to PhotoView"),
      onPressed: () => _toPhotoView(context),
    );
  }

  void _toPhotoView(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => const PhotoViewPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> photo_view_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';

class PhotoViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotoViewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PhotoView(imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/image.png"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pushing another route other than the PhotoView?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: i have the same issue after upgrade to Flutter 3. Earlier, it worked without these errors

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**UPDATE** - Fixed in photo_view [0.14](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view/changelog#0140httpsgithubcombluefireteamphoto_viewreleasestag0140---24-may-2022).

The problem is coming from [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) package.

In **pubspec.yaml** remove **photo_view** from **dependecies**

```
dependencies:
  photo_view: ^0.13.0
```

Add:

```
dependency_overrides:
  photo_view:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bluefireteam/photo_view
      ref: master
```

This way you will avoid errors in dependencies that come from the same version.

Comment: There are some packages that depends from this, and having the same problem, can't user temporary fix due to version dependency.

Comment: Although I did this, I´m still getting this error.

Comment: Other packages can throw the same error. You can also try to run flutter clean.

Comment: i had the same issue after i upgrade to Flutter 3. ( on earlier version of flutter it worked without errors )... after I replace the above solution, it is working again without error.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

To be honest you would be better off using InteractiveViewer than some unstable library for example

```
child: InteractiveViewer(
                child: Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)),
                  child: CachedNetworkImage( imageUrl: image,
                    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5) ,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.black,)),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                ),
              ),
```

you archieve the same effect if all you need is to zoom in

OR

You can rebuild and stop using hot reload

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the error was from, but switching flutter channel from master to stable fixed it.

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade --force
```